# Illegal option \xe2\x80\x93MultiViews

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am getting an error when I try to restart the Apache2 Server:

```
  ubuntu$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
  Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default:
  Illegal option \xe2\x80\x93MultiViews
  Action 'configtest' failed.
  The Apache error log may have more information.
  ...fail!
```

This is my `sites-available/default.conf`

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.example.comm
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testapp/public

    <Directory /var/www/testapp/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options –MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sh
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```